# Can Force UEFI installation harm isolated drives?

Tags: uefi

I am installing ubuntu on a Usb flash drive. I disconnected every drive except the installation media and the destination flash drive the force uefi install warning comes up after the partitioning section. Does the uefi installation mess with settings somewhere that can inhibit my ability to load windows when i plug the boot disks back in? Or is it just a blanket warning for if disks were in the system?

Comment: You should not have to force anything and yes you can do harm here. Impossible to know without the exact error message but my guess is your problem stems from unpluging the disk with the windows efi boot information. My advice is to plug in your drives and follow standard installation procedures. If you feel you have to unplug drives to be safe you should read the installation guide and have a clear understanding of Linux partitioning before you do anything. Failure to follow the defaults without an understanding of how Linux and EFI works == broken boot

Answer (score 0):

While as bodhi.zazen has mentioned you don't have to remove the hard drives from your computer to ensure they won't be touched.

However, removing them won't damage your computer.  Some users have recommended removing the hard drives with the most important data to be sure not to make a mistake and install on the wrong drive, or something else to that effect.

As far as the Ubuntu installer damaging your computer, that will not happen.

I have used computers many times that don't have hard drives in them.  I have also seen occasions where some very compact computers are shipped without hard drives with Windows 10 preinstalled on an sdcard.

I'm sure all the computers of today can boot from a USB Drive.  So if you're concerned about interfering with your current installation, you can set it aside while you explore, experiment, and become very familiar with working with your computer in a very safe environment.

Reading and studying all the technical information and steps provided in the installation is good.  If it would ease your mind knowing that during your install, you won't make a mistake and formatted the wrong drive, the experience you gain couldn't hurt.

You would need, of course, two USB drives.  One for your the LiveUSB Ubuntu installer, and one for your target.  The installer could also be a DVD instead of the USB media.

Using the method of disconnecting your internal drive, you can easily explore all the modes of the installer, then when it's time to plug in your internal drive, you can do it with more confidence.

I would recommend that you use the EFI install option.  This way when you decide to plug in your Windows 10 it will be easy to add the boot menu to the Grub, just by running the command `sudo update-grub` after it's plugged in.  The next time you boot you'll have a choice of which OS to run without having to go into the BIO to make the choice.

I would like to reiterate, that you can also do all this without unplugging your Windows 10 drive.  My answer was addressing the part of your question as to running the Installer damaging your computer, and add that unplugging your drives isn't a problem either.